# Backport Cognos Reports to Durable Model

Tags: report, business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I have a lot of reports developed on a model that is modeled with a design language (en-zn) and active language (en-us). However, when these reports were developed the setting "Use Design Locale for Reference ID" was not set to "True." Therefore, these are not "durable" if I change an active language query subject item's name. How can I make these reports durable? I have already re-published the framework package with the setting "Use Design Locale for Reference ID" set to "True."

Comment: As far as I know, if you update the reports to use the newest version of the package, you should be fine.

Comment: Actually the previously defined reports are only OK until you make a change to the query subject item's name in the active language. If the report was built before the model was published as a "durable" model, the report refers to the active language item name, thus it will break. If it was built after it refers to the design language item name.  The only way I see to fix this to make all reports "durable" is to re-build them by open and re-dragging each query subject item into the report in place of the existing item. This resets the reference to the design language name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make all reports "durable" you must re-build them by opening and re-dragging each query subject item into the report in place of the existing item. This resets the reference to the design language name. There is no easy way to do it. However, all future development will be durable.